# Is there a way(or a library) for making a smooth colour transition in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

First, a little of scenario. I have a tkinter window with a single button on it. This button is white until I hover over it, in which case it turns orange. My question is: How can I make the transition between the white and orange smooth, 
like a fade-in and fade-out. My code so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

root = Tk()

def bg_config(widget, bg, fg, event):
    widget.configure(background=bg, foreground=fg)
    #Fading effect here

btn = Button(root, text="Button", relief=GROOVE, bg="white")

btn.bind("<Enter>", partial(bg_config, btn, "#f47142", "white"))
btn.bind("<Leave>", partial(bg_config, btn, "white", "black"))

bt.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I do have wxPython library, if that will help. Are there any other GUI libraries or methods that could make these kind of tasks easier?

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by iterating over the difference in the *rgb* values of two different colors *(orange, white)*. Also, there are other python libraries like [colour](https://pypi.org/project/colour/) which makes the job much easier. Here, I made a function that uses [colour](https://pypi.org/project/colour/) library to **fade-in and fade-out different color options of widgets.**

```py
def fade(widget, smoothness=4, cnf={}, **kw):
    """This function will show faded effect on widget's different color options.

    Args:
        widget (tk.Widget): Passed by the bind function.
        smoothness (int): Set the smoothness of the fading (1-10).
        background (str): Fade background color to.
        foreground (str): Fade foreground color to."""

    kw = tk._cnfmerge((cnf, kw))
    if not kw: raise ValueError("No option given, -bg, -fg, etc")
    if len(kw)>1: return [fade(widget,smoothness,{k:v}) for k,v in kw.items()][0]
    if not getattr(widget, '_after_ids', None): widget._after_ids = {}
    widget.after_cancel(widget._after_ids.get(list(kw)[0], ' '))
    c1 = tuple(map(lambda a: a/(65535), widget.winfo_rgb(widget[list(kw)[0]])))
    c2 = tuple(map(lambda a: a/(65535), widget.winfo_rgb(list(kw.values())[0])))
    colors = tuple(colour.rgb2hex(c, force_long=True)
                   for c in colour.color_scale(c1, c2, max(1, smoothness*100)))

    def worker(count=0):
        if len(colors)-1 <= count: return
        widget.config({list(kw)[0] : colors[count]})
        widget._after_ids.update( { list(kw)[0]: widget.after(
            max(1, int(smoothness/10)), worker, count+1) } )
    worker()
```

---

*Here is an example to properly use it.*

[image]

```py
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
import colour  

root = Tk()

def bg_config(widget, bg, fg, event):
    fade(widget, smoothness=5, fg=fg, bg=bg)

btn = Button(root, text="Button", relief=GROOVE, bg="white")

btn.bind("<Enter>", partial(bg_config, btn, "#f47142", "white"))
btn.bind("<Leave>", partial(bg_config, btn, "white", "black"))

btn.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing in tkinter to directly support this. You will need to do it by creating a function that runs every couple of milliseconds and slowly changes the color.